# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar los dos valores menos recientes?

Tags: sql

Teniendo eso, necesito sacar los valores menos recientes, osea, el 29 y 30 (Monoica y Susana), pero solo consigo sacar los dos primeros valores, y no se exactamente porque, y me gustaría que alguien me ayudase, la linea de código que tengo puesta es la siguiente:

```
select  TOP 2   f_ingreso from  t_Ingresos order by f_ingreso ASC
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: intentaste reemplazar ASC por DESC?

Answer (score 3):

Estás ordenando de manera ascendente con `ASC`. Ordena de manera descendente con `DESC`.

```
select TOP 2 f_ingreso from t_Ingresos order by f_ingreso DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar tambien `LIMIT` para que obtengas únicamente 2 resultados y ordernarlos por la fecha (`f_ingreso`) en orden descendente (`DESC`):

```
SELECT * FROM t_Ingresos ORDER BY f_ingreso DESC LIMIT 2
```